# Highcharts align multiple piecharts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, highcharts

I made 2 pie charts using Highcharts from different data.

So they have different number of data as well as legends.

But I want to align them properly so chart by chart, legend by legend.

How can I do this?

I tried to set *max-height* of pie chart legends but that not works.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `chart.spacingBottom` and `chart.spacingTop` ([API Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.spacingBottom)) to create the same space on both charts like this :

```
chart: {
  spacingTop:15,
  spacingBottom:18
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/6hby35ao/)

Answer (score 0):

With `vertical` legend layout it will be better to use `margin` property:

```
chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    marginBottom: 80
},
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a62ztm5o/

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginBottom